# Is there any instruction to migrate from redux-form to react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-final-form

I working on a project that need to upgrade redux-form to react-final-form. I just wonder that is there any documentation for that task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:  There is now a [Migration Guide](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/migration/redux-form)!!**

---

I meant to make a migration guide, but it's just so easy that I never found the motivation to do it. But I'll write a little here for all of the people who find this excellent SEO-bait via Google.

---

Rather than "decorate" your form component with a HOC, you use  React Final Form's `<Form>` component inside your form component to give you all of your form state via a render prop. Most of the config stuff from Redux Form maps directly onto props to `<Form>`, e.g. `initialValues`, `onSubmit`, etc.

The `<Field>` API is *nearly* identical, but with the added benefit that you can define how your field is rendered *inline* via a render prop (using a "fat arrow" function as your `component` prop in Redux Form was forbidden and a common pitfall).  React Final Form has a few extra bits of field state, like `dirtySinceLastSubmit`, which can come in handy.

By default, Redux Form would *not* rerender your entire form on every value change, forcing you to use a [`getFormValues()`](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/selectors.md/#-code-getformvalues-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-gt-formvalues-object-code-) selector if you needed them in realtime. React Final Form *does* rerender on every value change by default because for most small forms, this is just fine. But  React Final Form allows fine tuning of rerendering via providing a `subscription` prop to `<Form>`, specifying exactly which pieces (slices) of form state you want to rerender for. Then, any time you were using a selector in Redux Form, you would use a `<FormSpy>` component in  React Final Form, which allows you to subscribe ("select") parts of the form state to rerender for.

As linked in the other answer, [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoSzy-4mviQ) explains the difference pretty well. More talks will be given later in 2019.

Comment: Who are ya. Anybody would think you made it or something. :p

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook Seems like he is an author. Take a look on contributors page https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/graphs/contributors.

Comment: @rzelek. He is founder of it :)

Comment: Hi Erik - for projects with a large number of redux-forms, is side by side migration possible?  Eg change over the forms one by one and have a mix of redux-forms and final-forms running at the same time?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You can do them individually just fine.